# Display images with same specific value?

Tags: wp-query, images, gallery

I'm trying to make a slider for my website, but I'm a little bit stuck right now. The thing is that I don't want to use any plugin (I prefer to try to learn how to do this, and also most plugins have extra features I don't need), and the solution I thought was to retrieve all images I have uploaded to the website.

I already know how to do that, since I did it in in another website, but the problem comes when I upload images that I don't want them to be shown in the webpage. Is there any solution for this? Something like only retrieving those images with same specific value...

Thanks in advance!

PD: this is the code I'm using for retrieving all uploaded images:

```
<ul id="gallery_list">
                    <?php
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'orderby' => 'post_date',
                            'order' => 'desc',
                            'posts_per_page' => '10',
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                        );

                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() );
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_the_ID() );

                        echo "<li><img src='" . $image[0] . "' alt=''></li>";

                        endwhile;
                    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an infinite number of approaches to this. Here's a couple that come to mind:

1) You could easily use something like `strpos()` or a regular expression to see if `$image[0]` contains a keyword. This approach would be a little less than ideal in my opinion.

2) Add a checkbox or 'tag' field to the media manager using `attachment_fields_to_save` and `attachment_fields_to_edit` filters. Then reference that field when querying the images.

3) Create a new section within WP Admin using `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` functions. Select, organize, etc.. from there. This route allows for the most customization and keeps management in a single place. In fact this paired with the second option would be the way to go in my opinion. If you're looking to learn how to create a plugin and use several hooks, functions and filters this would probably be an excellent project.